# Deleting lines that contain certain substrings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a lot of text files that contains lines that looks like this:

"2023-01-03T03:44:11.181Z","string2","string3", ...

I want to delete any lines that are not between times 18:00 - 20:00. In other words I want to get rid of all lines that do not have 'T18' , 'T19' or 'T20' and only keep the ones that do.

I've tried

```
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('output_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if 'T18' in line or 'T19' in line or 'T20' in line:
            output_file.write(line)
```

But the output file is completely empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: In the line you posted as an example there's no "T18" "T19" or "T20" string so the conditional won't trigger

Comment: Also, the logic in your script will _keep_ the matching lines, but still, there are none in your example.

Comment: Don't include `T20` in your `if` statement - it will cause you to keep lines like "2023-01-03T20:52:34.567Z", whereas your requirement is to only keep times between 1800 and 2000.

Comment: Sorry the text file also contains lines that start like "2023-01-03T18:30:05.511Z" ... for each hour of the day. How can I keep only the lines that have the str I'm searching for like T18?

Comment: you should provide at least a few lines as a sample from your original file to better understand your objective

Answer (score 0):

Try using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```py
import re

regex_query = r"T([1-2][0-9]):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"

with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('output_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        test_for_times = re.search(regex_query, line)
        if 18 <= int(test_for_times.group(1)) <= 20:
           output_file.write(line)
```

This regex expression searches for the instance of a `Txx:xx:xx` formatted time. It then looks at the first capturing group of the regex expression and determines if the number is between `18<=x<=20`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input file looks something like this below

for example: **input_file.txt**

```
"2023-01-03T03:44:11.181Z",
"2023-01-03T18:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T10:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T11:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T19:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T12:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T16:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T20:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T20:00:00.511Z",
"2023-01-03T04:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T20:01:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T19:59:50.511Z",
```

you can utilize the power of regex to match your desired lines. Here is the code snippet.

```
import re

pattern = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T(1[89]:\d{2}:\d{2}|20:00:00).[0-9Z]{4}'

with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('output_file.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if re.search(pattern, line):
            output_file.write(line)
```

and it saves your desired lines into the output file.

**output_file.txt**

```
"2023-01-03T18:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T19:30:05.511Z",
"2023-01-03T20:00:00.511Z",
"2023-01-03T19:59:50.511Z",
```